# Javascript window.location.href.indexOf is A and not B

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following to do somting when url contains gender=men&dir=

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("gender=men&dir=") > -1) {

      }
```

Now i need to say url contains gender=men&dir=  and not &dir=Schoenen do something

i was trying this only its not working

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("gender=men&dir=" || !"&dir=Schoenen") > -1) {

      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `indexOf` twice:

```
var hasGender = window.location.href.indexOf("gender=men&dir=") != -1;
var hasDir = window.location.href.indexOf("&dir=Schoenen") != -1;

if ( hasGender && ! hasDir ) {
    // Do whatever you want...
}
```

Comment: OP wanted "url contains gender=men&dir= and not &dir=Schoenen"

Comment: If the URL has to contain one and not have the other, the comparison should be && instead of || I think?

Comment: @IvoJonkers - Your question was pretty vague in its intent, but I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! I am getting same problem.

Answer (score 2):

`||` can't be used that way.

You need to state the `window.location.href.indexOf` twice:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("gender=men&dir=") > -1) &&
    window.location.href.indexOf("&dir=Schoenen") == -1) {

}

// > -1 is if found
// == -1 is if not found
```

If you want to change the AND (`&&`) into an OR (`||`), you'll need to replace `&&` into `||`.